# Asynchronous Caffeine cache with statistics

Tags: java, guava, caffeine

Following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-caching-caffeine) blog post about implementing a Caffeine async cache, we wanted to get the statistical data from the cache.

We are using version `2.7.0` of Caffeine

However, it seems that the `AsyncCache` has no access to its statistics:

```
private AsyncCache<String, Cat> asyncCache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
        .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .recordStats()
        .maximumSize(100)
        .buildAsync();

private Cache<String, Cat> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
        .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .maximumSize(100)
        .recordStats()
        .build();

....

cache.stats(); // this is possible
asyncCache.stats(); // no such method in asyncCache
```

Also, when checking the source code of the [AsyncCache](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/caffeine/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/AsyncCache.java) and comparing it to the [Cache](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/caffeine/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Cache.java) class, there is no `stats()` method in the async class.

Is there a reason for that?

Comment: You can use `synchronous().stats()` :)

Comment: @BenManes May I recommend writing that as an answer?

Comment: @BenManes what do you mean in `synchronous()` ? what is this object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AsyncCache offers a `synchronous()` view to provide a Cache that blocks until the asynchronous computation completes.

```
/**
  * Returns a view of the entries stored in this cache as a synchronous {@link Cache}. A mapping is
  * not present if the value is currently being loaded. Modifications made to the synchronous cache
  * directly affect the asynchronous cache. If a modification is made to a mapping that is
  * currently loading, the operation blocks until the computation completes.
  *
  * @return a thread-safe synchronous view of this cache
  */
Cache<K, V> synchronous();
```

This can be handy to perform operations, such as `invalidate(key)`, that doesn't have an asynchronous counterpart. It also provides access to statistics and policy metadata.

```
AsyncCache<Integer, Integer> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .maximumSize(10_000)
    .recordStats()
    .buildAsync();

// Perform application work
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  cache.get(1, key -> key);
}

// Statistics can be queried and reported on
System.out.println(cache.synchronous().stats());
```

In this case we expect the first miss to load the entry, so that subsequent lookups are a hit.

```
CacheStats{hitCount=3, missCount=1, loadSuccessCount=1, loadFailureCount=0, totalLoadTime=8791091, evictionCount=0, evictionWeight=0}
```